# Компилятор и Visual Studio Code видят разные функции под MessageBox()

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-code, g++

Недавно поставил Visual Studio Code, скачал расширение от Microsoft для C/C++, использую компилятор g++ 13.1.0 и CMake 3.26.3.
Всё хорошо работает, программы компилируются, но как только я попытался вызвать MessageBox, получился конфликт между Visual Studio Code и компилятором.
main.cpp:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Message", L"Box", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return 0;
}
```

Здесь 2 и 3 параметры имеют тип `LPCWSTR`, и ошибки не подсвечиваются, но как только я начинаю компилировать программу, вижу это:

```
error: cannot convert 'const wchar_t*' to 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char*'} 
    4 |     MessageBox(NULL, L"Hello", L"World!", MB_ICONMASK);
      |                      ^~~~~~~~
      |                      |
      |                      const wchar_t*
```

Как только я убираю приставку `L`, 2 и 3 параметры имеют тип `LPCSTR`, и программа компилируется, но жутко режут глаза сообщения об ошибках. Я понял, что Visual Studio Code видит эту функцию как `MessageBoxW`, но при компиляции она является `MessageBoxA`. Как заставить компилятор и Visual Studio Code видеть одну и ту же функцию?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать)

Comment: Visual Studio Code не более чем среда. Важно, чтобы компилятор компилировал без ошибок и предупреждений (конечно, не менее важно, чтоб код делал то, что от него требуется).

Comment: @Harry, ты прав, но это жутко режет глаза. Возможно ли это как-либо исправить?

Comment: `MessageBox` - это не функция, а макрос. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/conventions-for-function-prototypes Чтобы не было конфликта необходимо, чтобы параметры сборки, используемые для подсветки синтаксиса, совпадали с используемыми при сборке.

Comment: @user7860670, я хотел это написать в заголовке, но не стал, боялся что-то не так сделать. И получается для VSC и компилятора у него разные определения?

Comment: `MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Message", L"Box", MB_ICONINFORMATION);`

Comment: @AlexF, тоже вариант

Comment: Однако этот вариант не избавляет от необходимости синхронизировать параметры сборки.

Answer (score 1):

Советую попробовать clangd вместо C/C++ extension от майкрософт.

Плюсы:

1. опенсорсный, не принадлежит майкрософт, не нужен microsoft extensions marketplace
2. можно использовать для любой другой среды, не только VSCode
3. можно настроить много семантического хайлатинга, т.е. раскрашивания кода не по регуляркам, а по C++ категориям (например, все классы одним цветом, а все операторы - другим), которые регулярки определяют неточно; в С/C++ extension меньше опций для этого

Он должен автоматически использовать те же опции, что ты используешь при сборке. Он берёт их из файла compile_commands.json, который обычно генерится автоматически исходя из твоего CMakeFiles.txt или Makefile. Так что если там будут другие опции, то ты сразу увидишь, почему так.

Comment: А почему когда я захожу в настройки расширения, у меня там 9 опций? Где можно настроить хайлайтинг, форматирование и т.п.?

Comment: +1. Если еще и поставить кланг в качестве компилятора, то IDE никогда не будет спорить с компилятором.